# Jquery-UI Draggable Does Not Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

Don't mark this as a duplicate. I have been reading through all the posts with similar problems. No matter what I do, my code won't work.

I've had this problem happen before.
Most of the time it is due to a double inclusion or I just forget to include the jQuery-ui library all together.
But this time no matter what I do I get the classic

```
$(...).draggable is not a function
```

Here is a list of things I have done.

- Used CDN instead of local install
- Cleared Cache in web browser
- Made sure there were no double inclusions
- made sure jQuery-ui came directly after jQuery
- I am not using any other jQuery plugins
- Made custom build with only draggable, still didn't work.
- My div has content and isn't empty
- I went into the console and tried making a draggable div

Here are my header scripts

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Here a Jsfiddle working with libraries you just posted https://jsfiddle.net/zdhd25gh/

Comment: Ok I copied the jQuery-UI and Jquery from your jsfiddl and I'm still getting the same errors. So it must be something in my code that I can't find.

Comment: Some error is shown? Can you post your code?

Comment: My code and error message is already posted.